# decltype in static_assert

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, static-assert

Why this (static_assert) in a definition of a class doesn't work?

```
template<class IntT, IntT low = IntT(), IntT high = IntT()>
struct X 
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(low),decltype(high)>::value,"Different types not allowed");
};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int low, high;

    X<char,1,'a'> x;//HERE I SHOULD GET ERROR
    cout << sizeof(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are 'low' and 'high'? Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Downvoted: Incomplete --missing information on what `low` and `high` are-- and don't even care to answer requests from the people that is willing to help.

Comment: @David I specifically didn't provide info on what low and high are for the reason that this construct doesn't (or seems to) work on any type. But updated my answer.

Comment: @David it wasn't neither trick nor joke. I'm not sure where you get your attitude from but it isn't the healtiest.

Comment: @David and what I meant by any type was variable of any type. In my OP I didn't provide types did I?

Comment: Since `low` is declared as `IntT low` and `high` as `IntT high`, `decltype(low)` and `decltype(high)` are by definition `IntT`. Thus the static_assert will never trigger. If you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish, we may be able to suggest an alternantive approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static_assert` works fine, is your code that never assert. 
The template `struct X` defines `low` and `high` as of type `IntT`. They are both the same type, whatever values they have. 
When you instantiate the struct (`X<char,1,'a'> x`) you are telling the compiler that the type of `IntT` is `char` and are giving to `low` the value `1` and to `high` the value `'a'` (i.e. 97). However, the type of `low` and `high` is always `char` so the `static_assert` will never assert.